# How to use a react component fetched from an api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components

I have an api which provides me a with Webpack processed react component which looks like the following:

```
module.exports=function(e){var t={};function r(n){if(t[n])return t[n].exports;var u=t[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[n].call(u.exports,u,u.exports,r),u.l=!0,u.exports}return r.m=e,r.c=t,r.d=function(e,t,n){r.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},r.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},r.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=r(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var n=Object.create(null);if(r.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var u in e)r.d(n,u,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,u));return n},r.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return r.d(t,"a",t),t},r.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},r.p="",r(r.s=1)}([function(e,t){e.exports=require("react")},function(e,t,r){"use strict";r.r(t);var n=r(0),u=r.n(n);function o(){return u.a.createElement("div",null,"Pie Chart")}r.d(t,"default",(function(){return o}))}]);
```

Inside of a react component I want to fetch this component and display it. This is what I tried so far but unfortunately it does not work. The api fetch works but it just displays the component as string.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export function PluginGenerator() {

  const [plugin, setPlugin] = useState(<></>)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getComponent(){
      const {data} = await axios.get('https://api.example.com/plugin', { withCredentials: true })
      setPlugin(data)
    }
    getComponent()
  })

  return (<>{plugin}</>)
}
```

How could I go about using this from the api fetched component inside my code?

Comment: Hi @thiloilg, were you able to download react component from an api/static hosting ?  I tried lazy loading but I am not able to find how to webpack the component correctly. I asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256458/react-dynamically-download-components-and-get-data-from-all-child-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the newest chrome you can do something like this:

```js
const ProfilePage = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ 'https://api.example.com/profile-page.mjs'));

<Suspense fallback={<div>Please wait for component to be loaded</div>}>
  <ProfilePage />
</Suspense>
```

ProfilePage will be a lazy component. It will be loaded once the fetch completed. While you wait you will see the fallback.

More info:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

It is an experimental features!

Comment: I already tried it and it works pretty good for lazy loading. In this case I get the component from an external api so I cant really use React.lazy() or at least i did not figure it out yet. I tried an external link but than React.lazy() tells me that it cant find the file. Also I need to pass a verification token for the request.

Comment: It's exactly the same. React lazy needs a function than returns promise. you can create your own. E.g.  `React.laazy(()=>new Promise(resolve=> {here you can code. fetch; axios with credentials; resolve(the components)`

Comment: The component is coming back as `string`, not the actual component itself @AminadavGlickshtein

Comment: This is very tricky. You can `var module={exports:''}; eval(componentString); MyComponent=module.exports;`

Comment: I wonder how they do it in React.lazy under the hood, I mean they have to use eval() too right? I can also return the component from the api as file if that helps

Comment: New browser are supporting import js files using regular import keyword. It's not related to react lazy. But it's only supported when the server response header is `text/javascript`

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein So can the imported source also be from an external api?

Comment: If it's text/javascript yes. The browser can execute it using the import keyword. But if it just text, usaully you can't read text from external websites.