# React Dynamically download Components and get data from all child components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and this is more of a design question where I intend to
1) Download Components from static hosted site and display them.
2) Get all data from Components through (lets say) a download option

Based on my practice, I learnt that parent component passes a callback/onChangehandle to child as props and it maintains a copy of the state of child components though child components render the HTML. However, I want to dynamically download components from API/Static hosting based on user's input and then get a string representation/state of data from all these components. Each component would have different state data and thus I cannot write a common onChangehandle.

Question:-

1) Is such a design possible with react ? Will each component be able to upload its lib to cloud ?

2) Can we enforce methods to be written on each component so that parent can call each component's specific method and get the data ?

Pseudo Code I am looking for:-

```
class Parent extends Component {
    downloadData = (event) => {
        for(childComponents 1 to n){
            all_data += childComponent.getState()
        }
        pdf(all_data)
    }

    render(){
        // Render Child components
        for(childComponents 1 to n) {
        ChildComponent = // Load from API/Static hosting
        }
        <button onClick="downloadData"/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something kind of like server-side rendering?

Comment: No, the client renders but it loads the components dynamically. Imagine these to be plugins of different kinds. One could be chart, one could be table etc. Each component would call its own backend API, fetch data and display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json#dynamic-component-rendering-with-react

Comment: Thanks, let me read through

Comment: This still looks like we need to include the component during the build. I am looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018834/how-to-use-a-react-component-fetched-from-an-api

Comment: I found react lazy and react-dynamic-import which can import components dynamically. But I can only do it from within the src/ directory. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dynamic-import Here instead of ./realComponent.js, is there any way I can specify the URL of the component? However, the react lib in URL shouldn't be in transpiled js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is definitely possible. I am not really into class components so I wrote the example with react hooks.

> What you can do to load data from an external component is the following: Pass down a callback into the component which you call on a successful load to receive the data. Nevertheless I would not suggest to do so. I would fetch the data from a different api than the components. You should always split data to visualise and components which represent the user interface.

Code to load an external react module:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

export function Loader({ id }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const ref = useRef()

  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchReactComponent() {
      await import(
        /*webpackIgnore: true*/ `https://example.com/react-components/${id}`
      ).then(module => {
        setLoading(false)
        const node = module["ReactComponent"](data, setData)

        if (ref.current) {
          ref.current.innerHTML = ''
          if (typeof node === 'string') {
            ref.current.innerHTML = node
          } else {
            ref.current.appendChild(node)
          }
        }
      })
    }

    fetchReactComponent()
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [id])

  return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <div ref={ref} />
}
```

External React module:

```
function ReactComponent(data, setData) {
  // do something with the data
  return '<h1>A component</h1>'
}

export { ReactComponent }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works. I am experimenting with class components and having its own events handlers. I noticed that the return can only be a string, otherwise I get Syntax error while parsing.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, can I write the external component in jsx and webpack it after babel transpilation? What should be the export format using webpack for external component ?

Comment: @user3201336 I think webpack currently does not support to bundle a single module. You can use the bundler `rollup` for this. Search for setup react component library with rollup. With rollup you can bundle es6 modules.

Comment: Thank you very much. I setup a rollup config and created an es bundle. But I get `ReferenceError: react is not defined`  Below is the bundled js first few lines created for a dummy class component I wrote. The class component works with normal imports. Just wondering why import() fails with this error                                                                                                                 `import React, { Component } from 'react';
function checkDCE() {`

Comment: @user3201336 you have to include react into the bundle created by rollup.

Comment: I did use react in my rollup config.                                                      `// node-resolve will resolve all the node dependencies
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'src/components/js/Form.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/Form.js',
    format: 'es'
  },
  // All the used libs needs to be here
  external: [
    'react', 
    'react-proptypes'
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    })
  ]
}`

Comment: Thank you so far for the support and help. I learned a lot. I posted a new question on the issue. Please check if you find free time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684535/error-resolving-module-specifier-react-while-doing-dynamic-import-from-api

Comment: Thank you for the support again. I now solved all the issues I faced developing this architecture. Thanks for making this happen