# How to dynamically include a module in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to dynamically do a dynamic import **`import (this.props.myImportModulePath)`** but I get :

```
Error: TrasformError index.js: index.js:Invalid call at line 12: import(_this.props.myImportModulePath), js engine: hermes
```

I am not sure that this is the way to go about it, but what I am trying to get is to get `import ToastExample from './ToastExample';` dynamically.

Below is how I go about it.

Thank you all in advance.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text} from 'react-native';

import {name as appName} from './app.json';

class HelloWorld extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            OtherComponent: React.lazy(() => import (this.props.myImportModulePath))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>HELLO World</Text>
        );
    }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HelloWorld);
```

Please note that this works when I change

**`OtherComponent: React.lazy(() => import (this.props.myImportModulePath))`**

into

**`OtherComponent: React.lazy(() => import ('./myImportModule'))`**,

that is, passing the path directly as a string `'./myImportModule'` instead of passing it as a `prop` value `this.props.myImportModulePath`

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use import dynamically but you can dynamically change which component you are calling instead, syntax is as mentioned in this post: [React - Dynamically Import Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268507/react-dynamically-import-components)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to according to some condition to import some components. I think you can do it as the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
      const { path } = this.props;
      // here your path is your full, if you use relative path, you have to add 
      // prefix
      // here you can add your condition
      import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))   
   }

render() {
  const { module: Component } = this.state; 
  <View>
  {Component && <Component path='./Footer' />} 
  </View>
}
```

if you want to use flatlist, your can try use it `columnWrapperStyle` style.